# How to smooth scroll on CTRL+F

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

This [website](https://caseable.com/us/en/products/) does a smooth scroll when finding something through CTRL+F. I would like to have a similar effect through jQuery. I tried adding the following code in my footer but it doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: doesnt smooth scroll for me on firefox

Comment: @Flame Try it on Chrome.

Comment: it works on Chrome yes. That makes me think its a browser thing, so the website you linked does not use jquery for it. In fact it doesnt seem to use jQuery at all

Answer (score 0):

use the `swing` attribute to set the easing. You can change the animation duration also.

```
var body = $("html, body");
body.stop().animate({scrollTop:0}, 1000, 'swing', function() {    
});
```

for more check https://api.jquery.com/animate/